# How to extract and play animation in react-three-fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

Well I have .gltf animated model. I was successful in loading the model but wasn't able to play the embedded animation. I would like to know if in any way one can resolve it. Btw I am working this in react. Thank you in advance.

Here you can find the model
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZVyklaQuqKbSliu33hFxdyNpg4EQtcBH/view?usp=sharing

Here is the code that I tried.

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"
import React, { Suspense,useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas ,extend, useThree, useFrame} from 'react-three-fiber'
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import './style.module.css'

extend({ OrbitControls })

function Hardware() {
  const [scene, set] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
  new GLTFLoader().load("tern_construct_animation.gltf", gltf => {
    set(gltf.scene)
    const mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene)
    gltf.animations.forEach(clip => mixer.clipAction(clip).play())
  })
}, [])

return scene ? <primitive object={scene} /> : null

}

const Controls = () => {
  const orbitRef = useRef()
  const { camera, gl } = useThree()

  useFrame(() => {
    orbitRef.current.update()
  })

  return (
    <orbitControls
      autoRotate
      maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 3}
      minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 3}
      args={[camera, gl.domElement]}
      ref={orbitRef}
    />
  )
}
const animated_element = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 5] }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={2} />
      <pointLight position={[40, 40, 40]} />
      <Controls/>
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Hardware/>
      </Suspense>
    </Canvas>
  )
}

export default animated_element;
```

Comment: What do you see if you do `console.log(gltf.animations)`? Is anything in there?

Comment: Yes I do get an array with numerous AnimationClip items. Check out here I have posted the [image of the console](https://imgur.com/yjcVmug) @Marquizzo

Answer (score 15):

I struggled with the same.

Here's the code that worked for me.

Obviously this component is wrapped with `Suspense` higher in the tree.

```
import { useLoader, useFrame } from 'react-three-fiber';
import { 
    GLTFLoader 
} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import * as THREE from 'three'

const Model = props => {
    const model = useLoader(
        GLTFLoader,
        props.path
    )

    // Here's the animation part
    // ************************* 
    let mixer
    if (model.animations.length) {
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(model.scene);
        model.animations.forEach(clip => {
            const action = mixer.clipAction(clip)
            action.play();
        });
    }

    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        mixer?.update(delta)
    })
    // *************************

    model.scene.traverse(child => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            child.castShadow = true
            child.receiveShadow = true
            child.material.side = THREE.FrontSide
        }
    })

    return (
        <primitive 
            object={model.scene}
            scale={props.scale}
        />
    )
}

export default Model;
```

Comment: Thanks, `useFrame((state, delta) => { mixer?.update(delta) })` worked for me. I was previously trying to use `useFrame(({ clock }) => mixer?.update(clock.getDelta()));`

Comment: works like a chaarm! even when drei useAnimation hook is not working for me.

Comment: You save me... thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `@react-three/drei` you can also do the following:

```
    import {useAnimations} from '@react-three/drei'

    const model = useLoader(
        GLTFLoader,
        props.path
    ) 

    const modelAnimations = useAnimations(model.animations)
    
    useEffect(() => {
      modelAnimations.actions[modelAnimations.names].play()
    }, [])
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `modelAnimations.names` is an array of strings. 

Comment: @RyanSoderberg I think what he's implying with untested code is that you need to choose the name to select an action with: `modelAnimations.actions[modelAnimations.names[indexOfTheAnimationYouWantToPlay]].play()`, for example `modelAnimations.actions[modelAnimations.names[0]].play()`